# Upload form validation call back error Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have  function where i want to upload data and have its upload errors validated.. but the problem is i got this error `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Document.`

public function register(){

```
 $this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_NAME',  'Document Name'    ,'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_TYPE',  'Document Type'    ,'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('DOC_DATE',  'Date'             ,'trim|required');

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_pdf_upload');

 if($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE){

     echo "Account Created Successfully";

 }else{
      $this->add_view();
 }



}




function pdf_upload(){

  if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0){

    $upload_dir = './uploads/pdf';

    if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {

         mkdir($upload_dir);

    }  

    $config['upload_path']   = $upload_dir;

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';

    //$config['file_name']     = 'userimage_'.substr(md5(rand()),0,7);

    //$config['overwrite']     = false;

    $config['max_size']  = '5120';



    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){

        $this->form_validation->set_message('userfile', $this->upload->display_errors());

        return false;

    }  

    else{

        $this->upload_data['userfile'] =  $this->upload->data();

        return true;

}



}  

else{

    $this->form_validation->set_message('userfile', "No file selected");

    return false;

}

}
```

i am well aware of the callback issues of HMVC on code igniter and already have the MY_Form_validation library. what is the error of this ? i also got the error `ERROR - 2016-07-15 15:47:35 --> Could not find the language line "form_validation_pdf_upload"` on my error logs.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this :**

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('pdf_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
```

Comment: You should use upload library for uploading file